How to know the simultaneous query number limit of an HTTP ClickHouse connection?
I used the following code in a Jupyter notebook to send several queries simultaneously:
import asyncio

import clickhouse_connect


async def query(order: int):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.2 * order)
    return await client.query(sleep_query)


n = 10
client = await clickhouse_connect.get_async_client(
    host=config["host"],
    username=config["username"],
    password=config["password"],
    port=config["port"],
    database=config["database"],
    secure=False,
    send_receive_timeout=7200,
)

sleep_query = "SELECT sleep(3)"

await asyncio.gather(*(query(i) for i in range(n)))

Until n exceeds 6, it works fine. But after this I may catch the following exception:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[31], line 13
      1 client = await clickhouse_connect.get_async_client(
      2     host=config["host"],
      3     username=config["username"],
   (...)
      8     send_receive_timeout=7200,
      9 )
     11 sleep_query = "SELECT sleep(3)"
---> 13 await asyncio.gather(*(query(i) for i in range(10)))

Cell In[30], line 3, in query(order)
      1 async def query(order: int):
      2     await asyncio.sleep(0.2 * order)
----> 3     return await client.query(sleep_query)

File ~\miniforge3\envs\sample_size_calculator\Lib\site-packages\clickhouse_connect\driver\asyncclient.py:96, in AsyncClient.query(self, query, parameters, settings, query_formats, column_formats, encoding, use_none, column_oriented, use_numpy, max_str_len, context, query_tz, column_tzs, external_data)
     89     return self.client.query(query=query, parameters=parameters, settings=settings, query_formats=query_formats,
     90                              column_formats=column_formats, encoding=encoding, use_none=use_none,
     91                              column_oriented=column_oriented, use_numpy=use_numpy, max_str_len=max_str_len,
     92                              context=context, query_tz=query_tz, column_tzs=column_tzs,
     93                              external_data=external_data)
     95 loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
---> 96 result = await loop.run_in_executor(self.executor, _query)
     97 return result

File ~\miniforge3\envs\sample_size_calculator\Lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py:59, in _WorkItem.run(self)
     56     return
     58 try:
---> 59     result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
     60 except BaseException as exc:
     61     self.future.set_exception(exc)

File ~\miniforge3\envs\sample_size_calculator\Lib\site-packages\clickhouse_connect\driver\asyncclient.py:89, in AsyncClient.query.<locals>._query()
     88 def _query():
---> 89     return self.client.query(query=query, parameters=parameters, settings=settings, query_formats=query_formats,
     90                              column_formats=column_formats, encoding=encoding, use_none=use_none,
     91                              column_oriented=column_oriented, use_numpy=use_numpy, max_str_len=max_str_len,
     92                              context=context, query_tz=query_tz, column_tzs=column_tzs,
     93                              external_data=external_data)

File ~\miniforge3\envs\sample_size_calculator\Lib\site-packages\clickhouse_connect\driver\client.py:222, in Client.query(self, query, parameters, settings, query_formats, column_formats, encoding, use_none, column_oriented, use_numpy, max_str_len, context, query_tz, column_tzs, external_data)
    220         return response.as_query_result()
    221     return QueryResult([response] if isinstance(response, list) else [[response]])
--> 222 return self._query_with_context(query_context)

File ~\miniforge3\envs\sample_size_calculator\Lib\site-packages\clickhouse_connect\driver\httpclient.py:229, in HttpClient._query_with_context(self, context)
    227     fields = None
    228     headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
--> 229 response = self._raw_request(body,
    230                              params,
    231                              headers,
    232                              stream=True,
    233                              retries=self.query_retries,
    234                              fields=fields,
    235                              server_wait=not context.streaming)
    236 byte_source = RespBuffCls(ResponseSource(response))  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    237 context.set_response_tz(self._check_tz_change(response.headers.get('X-ClickHouse-Timezone')))

File ~\miniforge3\envs\sample_size_calculator\Lib\site-packages\clickhouse_connect\driver\httpclient.py:457, in HttpClient._raw_request(self, data, params, headers, method, retries, stream, server_wait, fields, error_handler)
    455 if response.status in (429, 503, 504):
    456     if attempts > retries:
--> 457         self._error_handler(response, True)
    458     logger.debug('Retrying requests with status code %d', response.status)
    459 elif error_handler:

File ~\miniforge3\envs\sample_size_calculator\Lib\site-packages\clickhouse_connect\driver\httpclient.py:385, in HttpClient._error_handler(self, response, retried)
    382 else:
    383     err_str = 'The ClickHouse server returned an error.'
--> 385 raise OperationalError(err_str) if retried else DatabaseError(err_str) from None

OperationalError: HTTPDriver for https://ch.<domain>.com:443 returned response code 429

As I am aware, the HTTP error 429 means "Too many requests". But how to get limit parameters explicitly via ClickHouse SELECT-query or any other way? So that I may set up an asyncio semaphore at the maximum allowed number to evade the exception.

SELECT * FROM system.server_settings WHERE name='max_concurrent_queries'
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/server-configuration-parameters/settings#max_concurrent_queries
